# Prevent WordPress from automatically recognizing renamed directory while debugging

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to debug a WordPress plugin called "thrive-leads", so I have renamed the plugin's directory on my server, from "thrive-leads" to "thrive-leads-2" in order to disable it.  I then uploaded an old version of the plugin and named the directory "thrive-leads" in order to overwrite the broken version.

However, according to the file editor (pictured), I can see that WordPress has automatically updated itself to refer to the new directory: "thrive-leads-2", and therefore I can't force the version to change.

How can I stop this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your old plugin folder all the way out of the plugins folder rather than renaming it. Maybe `wp-content/unused-plugins/thrive-leads`